# Location: issue with multi-row af:inputText in ADF Essentials

Tags: oracle-adf

So I came across this interesting issue that appears to be a bug in only ADF Essentials. When testing with the integrated WebLogic with JDeveloper, I cannot duplicate this.

I have a multi-row `af:inputText` being used for a remarks field. It works great until I put the text `Location:` (uppercase or lowercase L) as the first text on any row but the first row, my application throws a 403 error...

```
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.remarks.inputValue}"
              required="false" columns="100"
              maximumLength="256"
              id="editRemarks" rows="3"
              label="#{userinterfaceBundle['label.remarks']}"
              contentStyle="white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block;"/>
```

Entering this text into the inputText causes the 403.

```
Transportation Request: Bus for 20 travelers
Date: 20 February 2021
Location: my house.
```

Moving the Location: to the top line does NOT cause the 403.

```
Location: my house.
Transportation Request: Bus for 20 travelers
Date: 20 February 2021
```

Placing any thing in front of Location: does NOT cause the 403.

```
Transportation Request: Bus for 20 travelers
Date: 20 February 2021
s Location: my house.﻿
```

As I said, this seems to only be an issue with ADF Essentials. We are using Essentials with one of our Glassfish applications, but I am unable to duplicate it with one of our WebLogic applications.

I thought of opening a support ticket with Oracle, but the last time we stumbled across an Essentials issue, they gave us the recommended solution of "migrate to WebLogic", which is not helpful at all...

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Maybe a possible idea for a code work around? Anything you have would be greatly appreciated.

ADF 12.2.1.4, GlassFish 5.0, Java 1.8.0_202

Thanks,
Dan M.